# Have to delete cron_last every time for cron.php to work

Tags: cron

I am having trouble running cron.php. For testing, I am just running it from the browser (my_domain/my_site/cron.php.) Basically, if I go into the database and delete cron_last from the variable, it works fine, for one iteration, but the next time I try to run it, it doesn't work (until I delete the cron_last value again)

I put watchdog statement in cron.php. From that I could see that it runs until it hits `drupal_cron_run`. That statement doesn't execute correctly.

`drupal_cron_run` in in common.inc, so I put more watchdog statements in there. It fails to run past `module_invoke_all('cron')`.

`module_invoke_all` is in module.inc, so I looked in there, but now I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't delete it with your code - it's set up after last cron hook finishes, so no matter what you do inside Drupal, it'll be set. If the last line that gets executed is `module_invoke_all('cron')` (in Drupal 6) or `module_invoke_all('cron_queue_info');` (in Drupal 7 real cron tasks are wrapped in `try catch` so this is the only really risky point), or if your server logs timeouts, it's probably a faulty module that fails to execute it's [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7), or too many modules defining it, so at some point it times out.

I see two ways to deal with it:

1. Use [Elysia Cron](https://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) and with it's GUI manually run cron tasks you need to test. That way even if single task will fail, other will get executed. they will be executed one at a time, if you set it up correctly, so less risk of a timeout. And you will be able to test which hook, exactly, fails to execute. Then simply uninstall faulty module, or fix it, and you'll be OK.
2. In MySQL, create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) that will delete cron_last value for you. PostgreSQL supports [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) too, and most of RDBMS support them or something similar to them. It will not solve your problem, but it's way faster than point 1. and it will get you going if all you need is *quick* and dirty hack.